# Why does the Google OAuth 2 authentication page not offer even though I do not have a valid token

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm trying to make a third-party Google connection to an Angular application via "angular-oauth2-oidc" But when I have a null or invalid token it's supposed to send me to the Google authentication page. But nothing happens

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthConfig, OAuthService, OAuthEvent, OAuthSuccessEvent } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { from, of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const oAuthConfig: AuthConfig = {
  issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
  strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
  redirectUri: window.location.origin,
  clientId: 'MY KEY',
  scope: 'openid profile email',
  
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GoogleApiService {

    constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService, private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {
      oauthService.configure(oAuthConfig);
    }

    logout() {
      this.oauthService.logOut();
    }

    login() {
      this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument().then(() => {
        this.oauthService.tryLoginImplicitFlow().then(() => {
          if(!this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken()) {
            
            
          }else{
            this.oauthService.loadUserProfile().then((userProfile) => {
              console.log('User profile', userProfile);
              this.userService.setUserProfile(userProfile); // Store user profile in UserService
            });
            this.router.navigate(['/admin/users']);
            
          }
          /*this.oauthService.loadUserProfile().then((userProfile) => {
            console.log('User profile', userProfile);
            this.userService.setUserProfile(userProfile); // Store user profile in UserService
          });
          this.logout();*/

        });
      });
    }
}
```

```
loginWithGoogle() {
    this.google.login();
  }
```

I try by all means to ensure that if I have a valid token then I can retrieve the information from the email to be able to send it to the back. But if the token is not valid then I ask the user to authenticate through Google